# Manual driver binding and unbinding in Linux not working as expected

Tags: linux, drivers, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get a card swipe reader (Brush Industries SideWinder) to work with my Raspberry Pi. I have a MagTek mini unit working just fine using some slightly modified [Github code](https://github.com/0ki/libMSRx05). (You can see similarly related post showing more of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054226/usb-device-read-not-reading-card-swipe) )

The problem seems to be that the company (Brush Industries) who made the card reader in question (SideWinder) only makes drivers for Windows and *not* for Linux. I thought I was dead-in-the-water but then I remember that Brush Industries claims “The Sidewinder effortlessly replaces IDTech, Magtek, Hamilton, and IBC models of card readers.” Which made me think "Maybe I can just use the MagTek driver on my Raspberry Pi instead?”

But this is where I’m stuck.

I followed this guide to [manual driver binding and unbinding](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) exactly and once I get to the part where I “Simply write the bus id of the device you wish to bind, into the bind file for that driver.” I get this:

```
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

…even though in my devices folder (`/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/devices`) I see a `1-1.2` folder containing all of the data for the non-working card reader.

So then, I found another guide telling me I should use `sudo echo -n 1-1.2 | tee -a bind` instead. If I do that I get `1-1.2tee: bind: No such device`

Now I’m completely stuck and I hope I don’t have to tell my boss I need to return these items and start over.

Answer (score 2):

The question is old but I experience the same problem and I found why.

If your device is listed in `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/devices` but you get an error trying to bind it with your driver, it's because the device is already bound with *another* driver.

You can find the guilty driver with (Driver=btusb)

```
 lsusb -t
```

…and then you can unbind the driver.

So for instance, if my address device is `1-1:2.0` and the guilty driver is `btusb`, you can unbind with following command :

```
 echo "1-1:2.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/unbind
```

The next binding command will wor:

```
 echo "1-1:2.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/your_desired_driver/bind
```